# apache-hadoop 3.2.1 filesystemmultipartuploader pathname <partnumber>.part is not a valid DFS filename

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to use apache-hadoop 3.2.1 Multi part uploader APIs to upload multipart to hdfs. `Here is the error I see [dispatcherServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname aGRmczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDAwL3dhcmVob3VzZS8xMTExMTExMS0xMTExLTExMTEtMTExMS0xMTExMTExMTExMTEvNGM0YzQ1NDQtMDAzOS01MTEwLTgwNGUtYjRjMDRmMzQ1OTMyNWY3MWVmN2UtYjZjYy00NTY4LTg0ODUtYzliZWQ0NWI4MjYyX211bHRpcGFydF82OGE5ZGY2OS0zYTRlLTQ2ODQtYTQ4OC1lZjA1OWIwYzBhYTE=/1.part from aGRmczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDAwL3dhcmVob3VzZS8xMTExMTExMS0xMTExLTExMTEtMTExMS0xMTExMTExMTExMTEvNGM0YzQ1NDQtMDAzOS01MTEwLTgwNGUtYjRjMDRmMzQ1OTMyNWY3MWVmN2UtYjZjYy00NTY4LTg0ODUtYzliZWQ0NWI4MjYyX211bHRpcGFydF82OGE5ZGY2OS0zYTRlLTQ2ODQtYTQ4OC1lZjA1OWIwYzBhYTE=/1.part is not a valid DFS filename.] with root cause java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname aGRmczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDAwL3dhcmVob3VzZS8xMTExMTExMS0xMTExLTExMTEtMTExMS0xMTExMTExMTExMTEvNGM0YzQ1NDQtMDAzOS01MTEwLTgwNGUtYjRjMDRmMzQ1OTMyNWY3MWVmN2UtYjZjYy00NTY4LTg0ODUtYzliZWQ0NWI4MjYyX211bHRpcGFydF82OGE5ZGY2OS0zYTRlLTQ2ODQtYTQ4OC1lZjA1OWIwYzBhYTE=/1.part from aGRmczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5MDAwL3dhcmVob3VzZS8xMTExMTExMS0xMTExLTExMTEtMTExMS0xMTExMTExMTExMTEvNGM0YzQ1NDQtMDAzOS01MTEwLTgwNGUtYjRjMDRmMzQ1OTMyNWY3MWVmN2UtYjZjYy00NTY4LTg0ODUtYzliZWQ0NWI4MjYyX211bHRpcGFydF82OGE5ZGY2OS0zYTRlLTQ2ODQtYTQ4OC1lZjA1OWIwYzBhYTE=/1.part is not a valid DFS filename. at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:236) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.2.1.jar!/:?] at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$10.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:630) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.2.1.jar!/:?] at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$10.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:627) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.2.1.jar!/:?] at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81) ~[hadoop-common-3.2.1.jar!/:?] at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.createNonRecursive(DistributedFileSystem.java:648) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.2.1.jar!/:?] at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$800(DistributedFileSystem.java:131) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.2.1.jar!/:?] at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$HdfsDataOutputStreamBuilder.build(DistributedFileSystem.java:3295) ~[hadoop-hdfs-client-3.2.1.jar!/:?] at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemMultipartUploader.putPart(FileSystemMultipartUploader.java:85) ~[hadoop-common-3.2.1.jar!/:?] at com.anudeep.hdfswrapper.services.multipartupload.MultipartUpload.putPart(MultipartUpload.java:112) ~[classes!/:1.0] at com.anudeep.hdfswrapper.services.multipartupload.Requests.putPart(Requests.java:83) ~[classes!/:1.0] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_252] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_252] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_252] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_252] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.7.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.7.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118) ~[spring-web-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.9.RELEASE] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_252] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_252] at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.22.jar!/:9.0.22] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_`

I think this error seems to be coming because of missing starting pathseparator.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Like an error on my part, I did not decode and deserialize the handle id coming in request